# Problems to set volume of Cocos2d-X Simple Audio Engine?

Tags: android, ios, audio, cocos2d-x, marmalade

I am developing a game using Cocos2d-X 2.2.6 on top of Marmalade SDK 7.8.0 and I am having some problems to set the sound effect volume of theCocos Denshion Simple Audio Engine.

My code is this:

```
void AudioHelper::init()
{
    s3eResult result;

    context = GameContext::getInstance();
    s3eSoundSetInt(S3E_SOUND_DEFAULT_FREQ, 44100);

    audioEngine = SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine();

    preloadSoundEffects();

    setVolume(context->getSoundVolume());
}

void AudioHelper::preloadSoundEffects()
{
    unsigned int i;
    CCArray *keysArray;
    CCString *key;
    const CCString *sound;

    keysArray = soundEffects->allKeys();

    for (i = 0; i < keysArray->count(); i++)
    {
        key = (CCString *) keysArray->objectAtIndex(i);
        sound = soundEffects->valueForKey(key->getCString());

        audioEngine->preloadEffect(sound->getCString());
    }
}

void AudioHelper::setVolume(int volumeLevel)
{
    float volume;

    // Note: there are 6 volume levels in my game, they go from 
    // 0 (max volume) to 5 (no sound).
    volume = 1 - volumeLevel / 5.0;

    audioEngine->setEffectsVolume(volume);
}

void AudioHelper::playSoundEffect(const char *effectKey)
{
    const CCString *sound;
    int volume;

    sound = soundEffects->valueForKey(effectKey);

    if (sound != NULL)
        audioEngine->playEffect(sound->getCString());

}
```

The problem is that the sound effects volume doesn't change when I call the setVolume method, except when I set the volume level parameter to 5 (no sound). When this happens no sounds are played (as expected).

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you log actual values in this code?

```
void AudioHelper::setVolume(int volumeLevel)
{
    float volume;

    // Note: there are 6 volume levels in my game, they go from 
    // 0 (max volume) to 5 (no sound).
    volume = 1 - volumeLevel / 5.0;

    audioEngine->setEffectsVolume(volume);
}
```

you cannot mix float and int calculations in such a way. `float volume` here would be 1 or 0 anyway, because you are using `volumeLevel` as type int. your code should look like this:

```
void AudioHelper::setVolume(int volumeLevel)
{
    float volume;

    // Note: there are 6 volume levels in my game, they go from 
    // 0 (max volume) to 5 (no sound).
    volume = 1.0f - (float)volumeLevel / 5.0f;

    audioEngine->setEffectsVolume(volume);
}
```

also take into account that there is some limitations using CocosDenshion at win platform (no volume changing there).

Comment: Yes, I did log the values I was getting for the volume variable and they are float values, so this part is working. Since 5.0 determines a float type the result I get on the volume variable is also a float. This would be a problem however if my code was this: ` volume = 1 - volumeLevel / 5;` then the result would always be an int and the volume would be either 1 or 0.

Comment: I have retested my game, but this time in an actual device instead of the Windows simulator and now the setVolume function worked (the code is the same as the above), so I think that the problem is the CocosDenshion limitation that you mentioned. I cannot change the volume in Windows, but I can do it in a device. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

`s3eSound` expects values between 0-255 when setting the volume.

You can trace the current volume by calling:

```
s3eSoundGetInt(S3E_SOUND_VOLUME)
```

each time you set the volume to a specific value and see whether `S3E_SOUND_VOLUME` changes as expected.

I notice you use:

```
volume = 1 - volumeLevel / 5.0;
```

This results a value between 1 and 0 with 0.20 decrements if providing input values from 1 to 5.

Either these values are being set wrongly or being converted incorrectly by the Simple Audio Engine to the `s3eSound` values.

Tracing out both will give you more insight into what might be going wrong.

Comment: Hi, I've checked the `s3eSoundGetInt(S3E_SOUND_VOLUME)` you mentioned and the `audioEngine->setEffectsVolume(volume);` command is actually working. It is increasing and decreasing this property.